# How to do a log in authentication using Jquery and Json

Tags: jquery, json, passwords

i have  a server that if i make a call to it will return json files.
Basically i have multiple users that can be called.

```
ex: http://server.insource.local/users/145
ex: http://server.insource.local/users/146
ex: http://server.insource.local/users/147
```

What i want to do it to, somehow, send a username and password to the server, if correct send back one of those links that match that username and password.

The idea is not to use any php.

i will grab anything, any idea, any example.

a serve-side script example?
thanks

edit:
what i find out was that the link path is what is returning my info, and that the server asks for authentication anyway, so ill just check them one against each other

thanks guys

Comment: you need serverside code or else u are easily **HACKED**

Comment: you really need a serve-side script.. no matters what you want to do, you just need it.

Comment: +1 Neal, & ditto. Without serverside, you there won't be any 'authentication' - almost anyone with the know how can access those user's JSON files.

Comment: what kind of serve-side script? any examples?

Comment: I'm curious, what do you guys think are the pitfalls of this: 1.) JSON files are by default encoded, 2.) JS uses algorithm to decode JSON files based on username and password, 3.) If resulting JSON is invalid (it won't work anyway, gobbledegop would come back since decode is invalid) say invalid login data, else information access is successful...

Comment: you have to use some sort of server side validation. If you do it all on the client side it will easily be hacked because people can see your javascript information, reproduce calls...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider **AJAX** call with **jQuery**.

Here is sample code:

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
        url: "http://your-url.com/secure/authenticate.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        //json object to sent to the authentication url
        data: '{"userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
        success: function (){
            //do any process for successful authentication here
        }
    });
```

Of course, you would first have to collect user's entered value from *userName* and *password* fields.

On the server side, you can do all the verification and send back simple message such as *authenticated* or *failed*. The **success** part of the **ajax** call is for you to do any process after the user is authenticated.

More information about **jQuery AJAX** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

** **UPDATE** **

Say you have this HTML codes:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text" maxlength="30" />
<br />
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text" maxlength="30" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" />
```

You can use this jQuery script collect user's input and make ajax call:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //event handler for submit button
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            //collect userName and password entered by users
            var userName = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            //call the authenticate function
            authenticate(userName, password);
        });
    });

    //authenticate function to make ajax call
    function authenticate(userName, password) {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
            url: "http://your-url.com/secure/authenticate.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            //json object to sent to the authentication url
            data: '{"userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
            success: function () {
                //do any process for successful authentication here
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: read the OP's question before answering: `The idea is not to use any php.`

Comment: The response will be a json object so you will need success: function (data){ window.location = data.url; }

Comment: @Neal it doesn't have to be php. The OP wanted to send user name and password to the server: "What i want to do it to, somehow, send a username and password to the server, if correct send back one of those links that match that username and password."

Comment: idk what the OP wants.. the question is just confusing

Comment: i have this input fields:

    `<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text"     maxlength="30" />
    <label for="password" class="label"><br /></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text" maxlength="30" />
    <a href="#" class="page">Login</a>`

HOW DO I CONNECT THEM TO YOUR SCRIPT?

Comment: thanks for updating your code. One more question if i may. The basic auth of the browser still shows up when i try to load the page, asking me for the username and password. Shouldn't your script take care of that? of i need to check some server settings? I'm just a bit confuse

Comment: and what authenticate.php does?

Comment: @Patrioticcow For question 1, go to `//do any process for successful authentication here` and modify it according to your application and rules and direct user to somewhere else. For question 2, authenticate.php is server code where you authenticate the user and this server code need to return data to jquery to indicate success or fail.

Answer (score 0):

Check following code:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
    url: "http://your-url.com/secure/authenticate.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    //json object to sent to the authentication url
    data: '{"userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
    success: function (){
        //do any process for successful authentication here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
    url: "http://your-url.com/secure/authenticate.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    //json object to sent to the authentication url
    data: '{"userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
    success: function (){
        //do any process for successful authentication here
    }
});
```